# Why Mysql do not create index in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration

- I am running MySQL 5.7.24.
- I have two tables: Table `a` and Table `b`, described below:

```sql
-------------------

CREATE TABLE a (

  id int(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  a1 varchar(255)        NULL,
  a2 varchar(255)        NULL,
  a3 varchar(255)        NULL,
  a4 varchar(255)        NULL,
  b5 varchar(255)        NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX a_idx_b5 (b5) USING BTREE

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-------------------

CREATE TABLE b (

  id int(11)         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  B1 varchar(255)        NULL,
  B2 varchar(255)        NULL,
  B3 varchar(255)        NULL,
  B4 int(255)            NULL,
  B5 varchar(255)        NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX b_idx_b5 (B5) USING BTREE

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-------------------
```

And I want to get data from table `a` and table `b` with the following SQL query:

```sql
select
    a.*,
    max_b4
from
    a,
    (
        select
            b5,
            max(b4) as max_b4
        from
            b
        group by
            b5
    ) c
where
    a.b5 = c.b5
```

When I have a lots of data (more than one million) in table `a` and table `b` it become very slow, so then I `explain` the SQL, and I got this result:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL | 3209319 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | NULL       | ref   | a_idx_b5      | a_idx_b5 | 1023    | c.b5 |     459 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | b          | NULL       | index | b_idx_b5      | b_idx_b5 | 1023    | NULL | 3209319 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

As you can see the `<derived2>` table don't have a `<auto_key>` which mysql will add to the subquery after 5.6! So this result why the sql become very slow.

But as the mysql doc describes [derived-table-optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/derived-table-optimization.html):

> The optimizer constructs an index over column f1 from derived_t2 if doing so would permit the use of ref access for the lowest cost execution plan.

Usually mysql will add an index in subquery, so my question is why mysql do not give an index in `<derived2>` table?

Comment: Why are you still running MySQL 5.7? Why aren't you running MySQL 8?

Comment: Thank your opinion @Dai,because my company use mysql 5.7,And I don't have the permission to upgrade mysql version.But it is a good idea to see what happen if I use mysql 8.0.

Comment: What happens if you change your query to use ISO SQL `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Are your `STATISTICS` up-to-date? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html

Comment: I use the command `ANALYZE TABLE`,so I think `STATISTICS` already up-to-date.

Comment: Is there a reason all of your non-key columns are nullable and without any check constraints?

Comment: I just use table `a` and table `b` for test,so I doesn't add any other constraints.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a good approach because query-performance depends on the query execution plan, and the query execution plan depends on many aspects of table-design, and this specifically depends on column types, `COLLATION` settings, `NULL` vs `NOT NULL` columns, and sometimes `CHECK CONSTRAINTS`: this is because SQL DDL _statically_ (i.e. _declaratively_)  describes the database, so the query-planner can use _all that information about the database_ accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index `b_idx_b5` on the `b` table is not being used because it does not speed up the `GROUP BY` subquery.  You should be using this index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON b (b5, b4);
```

This should allow MySQL to very efficiently find the max `b4` values for each group of `b5` records.

As a side note, I probably would have written your query using an explicit join, rather than an implicit one:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.max_b4
FROM a t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT b5, MAX(b4) AS max_b4
    FROM b
    GROUP BY b5
) t2
    ON t2.b5 = t1.b5;
```

But, both the above version and your original version would probably have the same execution plan.

Comment: Why _doesn't_ the `b_idx_b5` index speed up the query at all though? A `GROUP BY` query can still use an index on the grouping column(s) to eliminate the need for a table-scan, which is preferable when `b.b5` is a sparse column, for example (after all, the column is marked `NULL`).

Comment: @Dai Good point, and you might be right in some circumstances (although apparently the OP's particular query does not want to use the index).  The point I was making is that whether a full table or full index scan, the OP's current index does not get us much past either option.

Comment: According to the document:`During query execution, the optimizer may add an index to a derived table to speed up row retrieval from it.`,the drived table should have the key.But our execution plan the drived don't have the key:
1.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html
2.https://mariadb.com/kb/en/derived-table-with-key-optimization/

Comment: @jiangke You are misreading/misinterpreting what the docs say about this.  The index would be on the column `b5`, _not_ on `(b5, b4)`, and also this index would be added _after_ the derived table (aliased as `b` above) has been computed.  The docs do not say that an index is added before materialization.  But having an index materialization is precisely what is needed to speed up the overall query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Aliasing a base-table `b` to a lexicographically identical alias `b` in an outer scope should be downright illegal....

Comment: @Dai Agreed...that was ugly, maybe it would not even have worked.

Comment: Maybe the related question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158455/how-do-i-know-whats-behind-the-auto-key0-index-in-mysql